# Toggling <a> tag failing while using ng-hide/show and a boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have an up arrow on that should `ng-hide` if `this.showUpArrow` is equal to false and `ng-show` if `this.showUpArrow` is equal to false. `this.showUpArrow` is set to `false` on page load and only toggles to `true` when the top of the page reaches the specified `div`'s `.offsetTop`. I am getting it to recognize when it should turn the boolean to `true` once it reached the `div` fine and dandy. The problem is that it isn't `ng-show`ing the `<a>` tag that I want it to show when `this.showUpArrow` is set to `true`. What gives?

***Here is my HTML...***

```
<a href='' id='up-arrow-link' ng-click='landingControl.goToAnchor("wrapper")'>
    <img id='up-arrow' src='../static/images/uparrow.png' ng-hide='!landingControl.showUpArrow' ng-show='landingControl.showUpArrow'>
</a>
```

***Here is my Angular controller...***

```
myModule.controller('landingController', function($location, $anchorScroll, $window){
var _this = this;
this.showUpArrow = false;

    angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
        var elem = angular.element('#mystory')[0].offsetTop
        var topOfScreen = $window.scrollY;
        if (topOfScreen >= elem) {
            _this.showUpArrow = true;

        }
    });
})
```

It is worth stating that the `landingControl` portion of my `ng-hide` and `ng-show` statements is referencing my controller. I am using the `this` method instead of the `$scope` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke a digest cycle either with `$scope.apply` or `$timeout`.

> `$apply()` is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events, setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of exception handling, executing watches.<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)</sup>

This is typically done in a directive.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like what I need. Any idea of what that type of code would look like for my purposes?

Comment: so are you suggesting that I re-write my code in a directive and call `.apply()`?

Comment: Yes, and put the directive on the element `id=mystory`. That would be the "Angular" way of doing it.

Comment: and don't forget to remove the scroll handler in scope destroy event

Comment: @georgeawg The problem I am running into is that the directive is only compiled once on page load. It isn't checking the the user's positioning on the page everytime they scroll down, like it needs to. Any ideas?

Comment: You are registering an event handler with the DOM. That handler is invoked everytime there is a 'scroll' event. That will work both inside a directive and inside a controller. I need to see the code for your directive to tell what is happening.